# Not able to display data fetched from API in React

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and am creating a simple application. I can print the data obtained in JSON format from GET method in the console. However I cannot display them in form. Please help me in resolving it.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {ReactComponent as ArrowLeft} from '../assets/arrow-left.svg';
const TaskPage = ({ match,history }) => {
  let taskId = match.params.id;
  let [task, setTask] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getTask();
  }, [taskId]);

  let getTask = async () => {
    if (taskId === "new") return;

    let response = await fetch(`/task/task/${taskId}/`);
    let data = await response.json();
    setTask(data);
  };

      let updateNote = async () => {
        fetch(`/api/notes/${taskId}/`, {
          method: "PUT",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(task),
        });
      };

      let handleSubmit = () => {
        updateNote()
        history.push('/')
    }

      let handleChange = (value) => {
        setTask((task) => ({ ...task, description: value }));
        console.log(task)
        console.log("Handle Change:", task);
      };

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>
        <ArrowLeft onClick={handleSubmit} />
      </h3>

      <textarea
        onChange={(e) => {
          handleChange(e.target.value);
        }}
        value={task.description}
      ></textarea>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TaskPage;
```

The browser doesnt show an error for `task.description`. However I am not able to show it in the textarea field. It appears blank.react

Comment: What exactly is stored in `task` at the point where you are expecting the textarea to have content?

Comment: Please add your API result format in your post. But at least there are 2 mistakes. In your state `let [task, setTask] = useState([]);`, you initialized `task` as an array, but you used it like the object in `setTask((task) => ({ ...task, description: value }));`. And then, you print `console.log(task)` in `handleChange`, but this is not right because React's state update is asynchronous. You can't get the updated value as soon as calling `setTask`.

Answer (score 0):

If want to see if any API call happen and what was payload/response - open chrome's developer tools (right click -> inspect on any part of page) and select "Network" tab, look inside for your call, what was payload & response to confirm your API call is actually like you expect it to be. If everything fine there, then look at your JS code. Now there is no clue if API is even working.

Comment: agreed with Lukas, a picture of api response would be better to understand. Also I noticed that in `handleChange` you change structure of state from array to an object. `setTask((value) => ([...task, {description: value}]); `  Before your setState inside `handleChange`, resets the state to an object with whatever you input as input value. Of course this depends if you want to set new `task` object or change the already existing one ?

Comment: I'm trying to update the exisiting task